# VBA, Excel - Extracting Data from Website does nothing

Tags: excel, vba

Background:
I plan to host a LAN-party and want a few games listed in a excel so my friends can add games and a macro in excel does everything for them.
Problem:
I want to fetch data from a website and add it to my Excel file Games.xlsm using a VBA macro.
The debugger shows no error but I don't get any result.
It seems Excel does nothing...

Can someone help?

There is a table on the first worksheet of Excel. This has columns from A to F.

A: Image of the game

B: name of the game

C: price of the game

D: URL to the shop page

E: Brief description

F: Player count

Columns D, E and F are filled in manually.

Here is a picture of the table in which two links have already been inserted in column D:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNRNi.png

Here is a picture of the website from which the data should be taken. The required data are highlighted with red arrows and boxes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/abs1o.png

Each row of column D has different links to the steamdb.info website
Using these links, the following data should be taken from the database page https://steamdb.info and inserted into the respective rows of the columns:

A:

- The image of the game can be found in the section

```
"<img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/218620/header.jpg?t=1682603063" class="app-logo" itemprop="image" alt="PAYDAY 2" width="324" height="151">"
```

- I would like to format the image in the following dimensions: width: 324 height: 151

B:

- The name of the game can be found as

```
"itemprop="name""
```

C:

- The price of the game can be found under

```
"table-prices-current"
```

with a € Symbol.

I don't want to use Internet Explorer.

Here is my macro code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillTableWithSteamData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Dim url As String
        Dim http As Object
        Dim html As Object
        
        url = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
        
        If url <> "" Then
            Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            http.Open "GET", url, False
            http.send
            
            Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
            html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
            
            ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = GetGameImage(html)
            ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = GetGameName(html)
            ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = GetGamePrice(html)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetGameImage(html As Object) As String
    Dim img As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set img = html.querySelector("img[class='app-logo']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not img Is Nothing Then
        GetGameImage = img.getAttribute("src")
        ' resize the image to 324x151
        GetGameImage = "https:" & Left(GetGameImage, InStrRev(GetGameImage, "/")) & "324x151" & Right(GetGameImage, Len(GetGameImage) - InStrRev(GetGameImage, "/") - 2)
    End If
End Function

Function GetGameName(html As Object) As String
    Dim nameElem As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nameElem = html.querySelector("[itemprop='name']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not nameElem Is Nothing Then
        GetGameName = nameElem.innerText
    End If
End Function

Function GetGamePrice(html As Object) As String
    Dim priceElem As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set priceElem = html.querySelector(".table-prices-current")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not priceElem Is Nothing Then
        GetGamePrice = priceElem.innerText & "€"
    End If
End Function
```

Edit 2023/04/28:
I don't know how to answer on a comment and add code at the same time so it has to be this way....

So, what happens when you debug? Your 3 functions are trying to call methods which don't exist on the `html`-parameter of type `Object`, so they return empty strings. Remove `On Error Resume Next` and you will see the errors instead of hiding them. –
Olle Sjögren

If I remove that I get an

```
run time error 424: object required
```

at

```
Function GetGameImage(html As Object) As String
    Dim img As Object
    
    Set img = html.querySelector("img[class='app-logo']")
        
        GetGameImage = img.getAttribute("src")
        ' resize the image to 324x151
        GetGameImage = "https:" & Left(GetGameImage, InStrRev(GetGameImage, "/")) & "324x151" & Right(GetGameImage, Len(GetGameImage) - InStrRev(GetGameImage, "/") - 2)
        
End Function
```

But as you see I set my img as object.

Comment: So, what happens when you debug? Your 3 functions are trying to call methods which don't exist on the `html`-parameter of type `Object`, so they return empty strings. Remove `On Error Resume Next` and you will see the errors instead of hiding them.

Comment: Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: I can only get your code to work if I set a project reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and pass the html-parameter to the GetGame-methods as type `HTMLDocument` instead of `Object`.